# Plots not visible when using a line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-analysis

I am new to python and I am trying to plot x and y (both have a large number of data) but when I use a `plt.plot` there is not plot visible on the output.

The code I have been using is

```
for i in range(len(a)):
     plt.plot(a[i],b[i])

plt.figure()
plt.show()
```

[image: Result: with plt.plot]

when I tried a scatter plot

```
for i in range(len(a)):
     plt.scatter(a[i],b[i])

plt.figure()
plt.show()
```

[image: result: with scatter]

I am not able to understand the reason for missing the line plot and even when I try seaborn it showing me an error **ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index**

Comment: just `plt.plot(a,b)` without any for loop. Line (and scatter) plot does take lists as inputs.

Comment: What is b? b is not defined in your code snippet. Also for line plots, you dont need to run it in loop

Answer (score 1):

A line is created between two points. If you are plotting single values, a line can't be constructed.

Well, you might say "but I am plotting many points," which already contains part of the answer (*points*). Actually, `matplotlib.plot()` plots *line*-objects. So every time, you call `plot`, it creates a new one (no matter if you are calling it on the same or on a new axis). The reason why you don't get lines is that only single points are plotted. The reason why you're not even seeing the these points is that `plot()` does not indicate the points with [*markers*](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot) per default. If you add `marker='o'` to `plot()`, you will end up with the same figure as with `scatter`.

A `scatter`-plot on the other hand is an *unordered collection of points*. There characteristic is that there are no lines between these points because they are usually not a sequence. Nonetheless, because there are no lines between them, you can plot them all at once. Per default, they have all the same color but you can even specify a color vector so that you can encode a third information in it.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# create random data
a = np.random.rand(10)
b = np.random.rand(10)

# open figure + axes
fig,axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
# standard scatter-plot
axs[0].scatter(a,b)
axs[0].set_title("scatter plot")
# standard line-plot
axs[1].plot(a,b)
axs[1].set_title("line plot")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.linspace(0,5,100)
b = np.linspace(0,10,100)
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```

I think this answers your question. I have taken sample values of a and b. The matplotlib line plots are not required to run in loops